# SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'models.[object Object]' in 'where clause'

Tags: sequelize.js

want to compute the updatedAt column and then compare it with current date in where clause

```
const query = {
        where: {
            [sequalize.fn('ADDDATE', sequalize.col('updatedAt'), 5)]:
            {
                $lt: sequalize.fn('NOW'),
            },
        },
        force: true,
    };
```

error : `SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'models.[object Object]' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `sequalize` to `sequelize` :)

Second, your `where` query should look like this :

```
where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn('ADDDATE', sequelize.col('updatedAt'), 5),
        {
            $lt: sequelize.fn('NOW')
        }
    )
```